# Translate the next list method invocations to appropriate calls to functions in namespace list?

Tags: python

My homework say "Translate the next list method invocations to appropriate calls to functions in namespace list" confused to what they are asking?

> lst = [2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> (a) lst. sort()
>
> (b) lst. append(3)
>
> (c) lst. count(3)

Comment: Perhaps they mean change stuff `mylist.append(1)` (which invokes `list`'s `append` method by binding to `mylist` then passing `1`) with `list.append(mylist, 1)` which uses the unbound `list.append` method, explicitly passing `mylist` as `self` (since no bound instance exists, the instance must be passed explicitly too)?

Comment: Could you please add more information? I estimate some results but I also don't want to get someones head confused.

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add what they provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are all showing bound method invocations, where the first argument is implicitly the instance they were invoked on. That is, if `list` were a class defined in Python, the definition of `append` might look like:

```
class list:
    def append(self, item):
        ... do appendy things ...
```

and when `lst` is an instance of `list`, doing `lst.append(3)`, makes a bound method from `list.append` and `lst`, such that the `self` parameter is *implicitly* bound to `lst` when the method is called.

That's not the only way to invoke a method though. You can get an unbound reference to the method directly by accessing it on the class itself, rather than instance, then *explicitly* pass the instance as the first argument. So instead of `lst.append(3)`, which binds `lst` to `list.append`, then calls the resulting bound method with the argument `3`, you can do `list.append(lst, 3)`, explicitly passing both `lst` and `3` to the unbound `list.append` method.

It's a little unusual, but there are occasional uses for it. For example, a neat way to strip trailing whitespace from lines in a file as you read them would be:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, f):
        ... process line with trailing whitespace skipped ...
```

rather than:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        ... process line with trailing whitespace skipped ...
```

The `map(str.rstrip` works because `map` calls the provided function on each input value, then yields the result, and `str.rstrip(line)` is equivalent to `line.rstrip()` when `line` is a `str`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, helps when you're just starting to learn to code